# All Media Uploads broken after database prefix change

Tags: php, wordpress, media

I've recently changed my wordpress database prefix from wp_ to something else.

After doing so, none of my images are showing on the site.

When i go to Media within wp-admin, image thumbnails are all greyed out.

I've changed upload folder permissions and I've tried regenerating thumbnails but it's as if wordpress no longer knows the route to my uploads folder.

Has anyone come across this issue before?

Any help is much appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Try this once https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/157609/database-name-change

Comment: Thanks for the response. That plugin is no longer available for download